# Inject object Resources in Class Util (using Dagger)

Tags: android, dependency-injection, roboguice, dagger

I some time testing some things with Dagger, after overseeing the series of articles here: http://antonioleiva.com/dependency-injection-android-dagger-part-1/, went back for more information, I saw some good examples like these: https://github.com/adennie/fb-android-dagger, most of which focuses on injecting dependencies on `Activity`, `Fragment`, `Service` and related. I'm wanting to do a similar thing with RoboGuice.

**In RoboGuice**

```
public class Utils {

    @InjectResource(R.string.hello_world) private String hello;

    public void showLog(){
        System.out.println("String from injected resource : " + hello);
    }
}
```

**In Dagger**

```
public class Utils {

    @Inject
    Resources mResource;

    public void showLog() {
        System.out.println( "String from injected resource : "  + this.mResource.getString( R.string.hello_world ) );
    }
}
```

**I created an module in my Application:**

```
@Module( injects = {Utils.class }, complete = false, library = true )
public class ResourceModule {

    Context mContext;

    public ResourceModule ( final Context mContext ) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Resources provideResources() {
        return this.mContext.getResources();
    }
}
```

Tried this in my Activity

```
Utils mUtils = new Utils();
mUtils.showLog();
```

But I'm getting `NullPointerException`. Someone already did something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to inject the object using `inject` method.

Assuming your `ObjectGraph` is initialized in the `App` class which is a subclass of the `Application` and exposes public `inject` method with implementation like below:

```
public void inject(Object object) {
    mObjectGraph.inject(object);
}
```

After creating the `Utils` instance you have to inject its dependencies.

```
Utils mUtils = new Utils();
((App) getApplication).inject(mUtils);
mUtils.showLog();
```

**Edit:**

You can also use constructor injection (no need for passing the object to `ObjectGraph`)

```
public class Utils {

    private final Resources mResource;

    @Inject
    public Utils(Resources resources) {
        mResources = resources;
    }

    public void showLog() {
        System.out.println( "String from injected resource : "  + this.mResource.getString( R.string.hello_world ) );
    }
}
```

With constructor injection the object must be created by the `ObjectGraph`

```
Utils mUtils = mObjectGraph.get(Utils.class);
```

Comment: but what can otherwise without explicitly passing the object to ObjectGraph?

Comment: @André.C.S check the updated answer. I've added some information about constructor injection

Comment: First, thanks for listening to my doubts, I know this is a simple matter, and despite the learning curve in this lib be a little big, I'm convinced to use it for process optimization in relation to RoboGuice using reflection